# Easiest way to join a channel in python telethon

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I read telethon documentation to [retrieve an user-name](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon/wiki/Retrieving-an-entity) and [join a channel](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon/wiki/Joining-a-chat-or-channel). After some tries i wrote this code:

```
result = client.invoke(ResolveUsernameRequest('XXXX'))
channel = InputChannel(result.peer.channel_id, result.chats[0].access_hash)
client.invoke(JoinChannelRequest(channel))
```

This  code works fine but i want to know is there a better or simpler way?

Comment: it seems fine to me.:-) because you first need to have access_hash of the channel to be able to join it.

Comment: @tashakori I like there was a class or function that inputs `result` variable as argument (line 1) and returns the `channel` variable(line 2).

Comment: On the latest tagged version, you can remove the `.invoke` and perform a simple call, and you don't need to manually cast `Channel` to `InputChannel` as of upstream (not yet on `pip`, see https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon/commit/95a989be2c708d98be8feff70d33149c14441879)

Answer (score 4):

first upgrade telethon

```
from telethon.tl.functions.messages import ImportChatInviteRequest
updates = client(ImportChatInviteRequest('hash_invite _channel'))
```