# How to capture the channel messages in Telegram using Telethon?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telethon

I want to capture the channel messages and send them to another python function.
By using the documentation, I'm able to connect to Telegram server and do the authentication. However, I'm not able to find out how to capture the channel messages.

The documentation provides the following method:

```
channels.getMessages#93d7b347 channel:InputChannel id:Vector<int> = messages.Messages
```

`channel` is an `InputChannel`. Below is the documentation

```
inputChannel#afeb712e channel_id:int access_hash:long = InputChannel
```

I'm not able to understand how to get the channel_id and the access_hash.
Also I do not understand what to provide for `id:Vector<int>`

If I want to capture each message. Do I have to run this within an infinite loop? 
A small example will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Read [Obtaining your Telegram API ID and Hash](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon#obtaining-your-telegram-api-id-and-hash)

Comment: @stovfl I still don't know how to find the `channel_id` and the `vector<int>` entity. Also I thought access_hash refers to the channel entity. I will try to use the telegram API hash in place of it after I find out what is the channel id and vector entity.

Answer (score 1):

Relevant: [join-a-channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44996317/easiest-way-to-join-a-channel-in-python-telethon)

---

> **Question**: don't know how to find the channel_id

```
from telethon.utils import get_display_name

# Retrieve the top 10 dialogs
# Entities represent the user, chat or channel
# corresponding to the dialog on the same index
dialogs, entities = client.get_dialogs(10)
 
# Display them, 'i'
for i, entity in enumerate(entities, start=1):
     print('{}. {}'.format(i, get_display_name(entity)))
```

---

> **Question**:  I do not understand what to provide for id:Vector<int>

---

> [Core types](https://lonamiwebs.github.io/Telethon/#core)
> Vector<T>: If a type T is wrapped around Vector<T>, then it means that the argument should be a list of it.
> For instance, a valid value for **Vector<int> would be [1, 2, 3]**.

Comment: Unless I know what the vector parameter signifies, I do not know what to pass to it. Definitely it needs to know which channel id, so I pass the channel id but what does the vector parameter signify in this case? Thank you :)